# Cannot access a specific scene without crashing

Tags: scene

Blender 2.83.5

[image: system info]

I've got two scenes in my file and after finishing what I needed to do in one of them, I go to switch back to my first main scene and Blender immediately crashes.  No warning or error report- it's just no longer open.  This happens even after a complete restart.  I'd attach the file but it's 3.2GB.

If I open a fresh blank file and try to link or append the scene from the saved file, it still crashes when I switch over to it.  I've tried appending each individual collection (tedious and not ideal since linked things get wonky) but there are a few collections that force close the program.  I've tried deleting all of the materials in the entire blender project just in case that was part of it; to no avail.  Anything else I can do?  I am going to cry if I have to redo 6 weeks of work.

Comment: Does it crash in Solid shading mode as well?

Comment: I'm only in Solid shading mode.  I've tried it in Cycles, Evee and Workbench.  Doesn't matter.

Comment: So I've discovered that if I switch the display mode to scenes, toggle down the Scene Collections and hide the problematic collections, then I can get into the scene.  But the moment I try to "enable in viewport" any of those collections, the program closes out.

Comment: I was able to narrow down the crashing impetus to two specific meshes by toggling down the problematic collections, turning off "enable in viewport" for each object in the collection, turning "enable in viewport" on for the collection, and then turning each object back on one by one.  Luckily I can just import those two meshes from the obj file and everything is fine- but that the problem existed is still baffling me.

Comment: Sometimes project files just become corrupted for some reasons. It is great when it is possible to handle it somehow. You can try to launch Blender [from the Terminal on Mac](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/workflows/command_line.html), make your project crash and read the errors log in the console. Sometimes it helps to understand where the error comes from.